# Not able to redirect entire output of a command to a log file using shell script

Tags: shell

I'm redirecting output of a command to a log file in a shell script as follows :

```
script > file.log
```

However, towards the end of the script, some of the final content which includes key information like "PASS" or "FAIL" gets printed on the console rather than re-directed to file.log

I would like this information to be re-directed as well. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the output of `"PASS" "FAIL"` is output to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, so you want to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to your file, e.g.

```
script > file.log 2>&1
```

(or you can shortcut the command with `script &> file.log`)